# Выделение памяти для элемента структуры внутри функции

Tags: c, указатели, память, malloc

Есть простая структура :

```
typedef struct
{
    char* name;
    char* surname;
} data;
```

Внутри функции main я объявляю указатель на эту структуру и передаю один из параметров в функцию :

```
data* var = (data*)malloc(sizeof(data)); // Указатель на структуру.
    create(var->name);
```

Внутри функции пытаюсь выделить память под этот элемент и заполнить символами, но почему-то это не работает

```
void create(char* element)
{
    element = (char*)malloc(2 * (sizeof(char)));
    element[0] = 'a';
    element[1] = '\0';
    printf("%s", element);
}
```

Подозреваю, что выделяю память внутри функции под что-то другое

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте:

```
data* var = (data*)malloc(sizeof(data)); // Указатель на структуру.
create(&var->name);

void create(char** element)
{
    *element = (char*)malloc(2 * (sizeof(char)));
    (*element)[0] = 'a';
    (*element)[1] = '\0';
    printf("%s", *element);
}
```

Вам же надо, чтобы была выделена и заполнена память именно `var->name`?

Кстати, если вы работаете **именно в С**, не С++, то приведение `(char*)malloc...` излишне.

Comment: Да, это работает так, как нужно. А почему нам необходимо передавать именно указатель на указатель?

Comment: @GlebKamisaraw, читайте про передачу по значению/ссылке. Это классический вопрос.

Comment: @eanmos, спасибо!

Comment: @GlebKamisaraw, обращайтесь :)